# JetBrains GoLand. How to terminate a program?

Tags: go, debugging, goland

Primitive RestAPI. But the question is about goLand. How can I set up the debug configuration so that I can stop the program with the red stop button. Now I run it with go build + ./project_name, so there is no stopping and I have to re-enter the IDE. How do I set up the configuration? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGQm.png)

Comment: You're running your application via terminal and it is pretty the same as the terminal in your operating system. To debug/run your application via the IDE features with different buttons and actions, you have to create a run configuration. Please see the following docs sections to get more details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/running-applications.html & https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/debugging-code.html

Comment: Just in case, you can send SIGINT to your application that you've run in the terminal. On Windows, you can do it via the Ctrl+C shortcut.

Comment: @s0xzwasd I seem to be quite dumb because it worked with the basic config template, but it seemed to me that nothing worked, thanks anyway

Comment: You are very welcome. Feel free to provide a bit more details if it doesn't work after you set up run configurations.